# Open source file of a referenced project in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, in design time, when I encounter a call to a procedure, I can jump to the code of that procedure by right-clicking it's name and selecting 'Go To Definition' (or press F12) from the pop-up menu.

However, this does not work for a procedure in a referenced (DLL) file (not included in the project).

But when I'm debugging in runtime, I CAN step into that procedure pressing F10 when it's called. This makes me think it should be possible in design time too, but I can't find how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to be a smart-a$$, but: double-click on it.  Probably I'm not understanding you.  Give a better explanation, please.